# Нужно ли тире перед словом "есть"?

Tags: пунктуация

ДСУ — есть комбинация из двух сильфонов, работающих в режиме контркомпенсации.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ДСУ есть комбинация из двух сильфонов, работающих в режиме контркомпенсации.

При наличии связки "есть" тире перед именной частью сказуемого не ставится.

Answer (score 4):

Сам смысл употребления тире в выражениях тождества состоит в замещении отсутствующего глагола, в обозначении его места. При этом чаще всего подразумевается глагол "есть". Именно поэтому тире здесь не нужно.